# Johansen Test Results: highest eigenvalues equal to 0, lower higher than 0

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, co-integration

Suppose that we perfrom a Johansen test over three I(1) variables that give us these results through the maximum eigenvalues statistic:

[image]

as you can see, we accept the null hypothesis in the first step, so in theory we should stop and assume that there is no cointegration between the variables.

However, for the lower eigenvalue, we could reject the null hypothesis for 10% and 5% confidence level, so my question is: **why don't consider the last eigenvalue test as the proof that there is a cointegration relationship and why do we stop in the first step?**

Note: my question is fundamented in the fact that I have read that what we are actually testing is the rank of the matrix through the nullity+rank theorem, which states that the number of variables in a matrix (columns) - the nullity of a Matrix (the dimension of the eigenspace associated with an eigenvalue of 0) is equal to the rank. So in this case, rejecting the null hypothesis that the last eigenvalue is equal to 0 would mean that the rank of the matrix is at least 1.

Comment: This might be a better fit for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Comment: @RichardHardy I thought the same in the first plce, but there are no tags in cross-validated for cointegration, econometrics or mathematical economics, so i thought that it might be a better fit for Economics

Comment: There is definitely a tag for [cointegration](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cointegration) with 576 threads (vs. only 16 here)! There is also one for [econometrics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/econometrics) with over 2400 threads (vs. 1300 here). You can also add [linear-algebra](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-algebra) and [matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+rank) tags for a good measure.

Comment: @RichardHardy thanks, I might have been confused with another StackExchange section